# What are regions in transition in HBase?

Tags: java, hbase

The HBaseAdmin API has a method `getClusterStatus` inside which is the `getRegionsInTransition`. I wanted to know what regions in transition mean? I want to monitor certain HBase regions whose states are either in `FAILED_CLOSE` and `FAILED_OPEN` state, but there is no way to manually put a region in those state to test what `getRegionsInTransition` do. So my question is, what does that method return? Does it only return those regions that are transitioning, for example a region that was OFFLINE and now is transitioning to OPEN? I am using HBase 0.98.

Also, is there a way that I can get regions and what state they are in?